# Setting Up Own Web Server Using DynDNS

Tags: apache, web, dns

I think I heard somewhere that I can set up my personal web server using services like DynDNS. Is it true. If it is can anybody give me a simple step by step guide on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't said what sort of OS you are using but since you have hinted about apache have a look at the following. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS
I know that this is for Ubuntu but it has the basic steps.

Regards

Jonathan